# separate vs separated

Tags: adjectives

> 1. The product is made with two machines that are **separate** from each other .
> 2. The product is made with two machines that are **separated** from each other.

I would like to confirm my understanding regarding differences between "separate" and "separated" using the above examples I created.

I created the first sentence to mean that **the two machines are** **different machines**, and created the second sentence to mean that **the two machines are spaced from each other**.

Could you advise me whether my understanding is correct?

Comment: Your understanding is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first, the machines are different (separate) machines (and that's all it says). In the second, they could be different machines which have been deliberately kept apart (separated) for some reason (e.g. for safety where one uses gasoline and the other makes lots of sparks).